# How to convert a 3d numpy array to 2d

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3d matrix like this

```py
np.arange(16).reshape((4,2,2))

array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

        [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
        [14, 15]]])
```

and would like to stack them in grid format, ending up with

```
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  3,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 12, 13],
       [10, 11, 14, 15]])
```

Is there a way of doing without explicitly `hstack`ing (and/or `vstack`ing) them or adding an extra dimension and reshaping?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
In [27]: x = np.arange(16).reshape((4,2,2))

In [28]: x.reshape(2,2,2,2).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(4,-1)
Out[28]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  3,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 12, 13],
       [10, 11, 14, 15]])
```

---

I've posted more general functions for [reshaping/unshaping arrays into blocks, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873755/190597).

Comment: Ok, so considering I have N block matrices with `bm x bn` dimension and want to stack them in a `m x n` matrix, provided `N = m x n`, I would then have
    `x.reshape(m,n,bm,bn).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(bm*m,-1)`

Just wanted to know if there was any numpy function for this purpose. Thanks @unutbu once again.

Comment: if we expand on `numpy`'s official documentation on `reshape` (which is just a few words), it'd also make sense to read it this way: `ndarray.reshape(4th_d, 3rd_d, 2nd_d, 1st_d)`, the highest dimension always go in first.

Answer (score 0):

The convert a 3d array to a 2d one, `transpose()` is a very useful function. For example, to derive the expected result in the OP, after reshaping by adding an extra dimension, the second and third axes could be swapped using `transpose()`.

```py
arr = np.arange(16).reshape(4,2,2)
reshaped_arr = arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,-1)
```

[image: result1]

---

On the surface, it does the same job as `swapaxes()` but since `transpose()` allows any permutation of axes, it's more flexible. For example, to make the following transformation, two axes must be swapped, so `swapaxes()` will have to called twice but it can be handled with a single `transpose()` call.

[image: result2]

```py
reshaped_arr = arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(1,2,0,3).reshape(4,-1)
```