# Block mean of numpy 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, reshape, mean

I want to find block mean of a 2D array in NumPy. For simplicity, let us assume that the array is as follows:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

I want to divide this array into 3 blocks of size 2x4, and then find the mean of all three blocks (so that the shape of the mean is 2x4. The first block is formed by the first 4 columns, the next one by the next 4 columns and so on. So my blocks are:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])

array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

I can use a loop to do this but I get a feel that it would be better to first convert this array into a 3D array by `reshape` and then use the `mean` method on the 3D array along the third axis. This could be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990465/3d-numpy-array-to-2d).

Would appreciate if someone can provide me with:

1). An appropriate Pythonic command to do the block mean without even converting to 3D, if such a trick exists.

2). If not an appropriate Pythonic command to do the 2D to 3D conversion.

3). An insight whether it would be more efficient (in terms of space) to do it using a loop or by using the command above.

Comment: The question you have linked, or actually the answer, is one of the coolest numpy codes I have ever seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numpy methods are going to beat python loops almost always, so I am going to skip your 1.

As for 2, in this particular case the following works:

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
              [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
a = a.reshape(2, 3, 4)
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
>>> np.mean(a, axis=1)
array([[  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [ 16.,  17.,  18.,  19.]])
```

The trick is in the `reshape`. For a general case where you want blocks of `n` columns, the following is an option

```
a = a.reshape((a.shape[0], -1, n))
```

Your concerns in 3 are mostly unwarranted. [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) returns a view of the original array, not a copy, so the conversion to 3D only requires altering the `shape` and `strides` attributes of the array, without having to copy any of the actual data.

**EDIT**
To be sure that reshaping does not copy the array, but returns a view, do the reshape as

```
a.shape = a = a.reshape((a.shape[0], -1, n))
```

The example in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) goes along the lines of:

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> b = a.T
>>> b.shape = (12,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: incompatible shape for a non-contiguous array
```

And in general there are only problems if you have been doing `transpose`, `rollaxis`, `swapaxes` or the like on your array.

Comment: Thanks! This was cool! The reason I mentioned point (3) is because [numpy.reshape doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) mentions that the return could possibly be a copy, rather than a view.

Answer (score -1):

I can answer ur number 1).

```
vstack([mean(a[:,4*i:4*(i+1)],axis=1) for i in range(3)]).T
```