# Partitioned matrix multiplication in tensorflow or pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, pytorch, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

Assume I have matrices P with the size `[4, 4]` which partitioned (block) into 4 smaller matrices `[2,2]`. How can I **efficiently** multiply this block-matrix into another matrix (not partitioned matrix but smaller)?

Let's Assume our original matric is:

```
P = [ 1 1 2 2
      1 1 2 2
      3 3 4 4
      3 3 4 4]
```

Which split into submatrices:

```
P_1 = [1 1    , P_2 = [2 2  , P_3 = [3 3   P_4 = [4 4
       1 1]            2 2]          3 3]         4 4]
```

Now our P is:

```
P = [P_1 P_2
     P_3 p_4]
```

In the next step, I want to do element-wise multiplication between P and smaller matrices which its size is equal to number of sub-matrices:

```
P * [ 1 0   =   [P_1  0  = [1 1 0 0 
      0 0 ]      0    0]    1 1 0 0
                            0 0 0 0
                            0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: A few questions (assuming tensorflow is used): (1) Is the smaller matrix provided as a numpy array, a tensorflow constant, or a tensorflow variable? (2) Are all elements of the smaller matrix 1s or 0s? (3) Are the blocks P_1 ... P_4 of the same size?

Comment: @GZ0 1) The smaller matrix is the output of another multiplication.  2) Not necessary. 3) all the P_i have the same size.

Comment: Two more questions: (1) How large is the size of P and the smaller matrix in your problem? (2) Are all matrix multiplications done in Tensorflow / PyTorch (in some cases the matrix manipulation might be done in `numpy` before the result is loaded into Tensorflow / PyTorch for efficiency)?

Comment: @Gz0 1) The size of P is something between 256*256 to 4048 2) Yes, all matrix multiplications are done in tensorflow/pytorch.

Comment: Is the smaller matrix always of size (2, 2)?

Comment: @GZ0 No, it can be anything between 2*2 to 1024*1024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a general Tensorflow-based solution that works for input matrices `p` (large) and `m` (small) of arbitrary shapes as long as the sizes of `p` are divisible by the sizes of `m` on both axes.

```
def block_mul(p, m):
   p_x, p_y = p.shape
   m_x, m_y = m.shape
   m_4d = tf.reshape(m, (m_x, 1, m_y, 1))
   m_broadcasted = tf.broadcast_to(m_4d, (m_x, p_x // m_x, m_y, p_y // m_y))
   mp = tf.reshape(m_broadcasted, (p_x, p_y))
   return p * mp
```

Test:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

p = tf.reshape(tf.constant(range(36)), (6, 6))
m = tf.reshape(tf.constant(range(9)), (3, 3))
print(f"p:\n{p}\n")
print(f"m:\n{m}\n")
print(f"block_mul(p, m):\n{block_mul(p, m)}")
```

Output (Python 3.7.3, Tensorflow 1.13.1):

```
p:
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]]

m:
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]

block_mul(p, m):
[[  0   0   2   3   8  10]
 [  0   0   8   9  20  22]
 [ 36  39  56  60  80  85]
 [ 54  57  80  84 110 115]
 [144 150 182 189 224 232]
 [180 186 224 231 272 280]]
```

Another solution that uses implicit broadcasting is the following:

```
def block_mul2(p, m):
   p_x, p_y = p.shape
   m_x, m_y = m.shape
   p_4d = tf.reshape(p, (m_x, p_x // m_x, m_y, p_y // m_y))
   m_4d = tf.reshape(m, (m_x, 1, m_y, 1))
   return tf.reshape(p_4d * m_4d, (p_x, p_y))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can think of representing your large block matrix in a more efficient way.

For instance, a block matrix

```
P = [ 1 1 2 2
      1 1 2 2
      3 3 4 4
      3 3 4 4]
```

Can be represented using

```
a = [ 1 0    b = [ 1 1 0 0    p = [ 1 2
      1 0          0 0 1 1 ]        3 4 ]
      0 1
      0 1 ]
```

As

```
P = a @ p @ b
```

With (`@` representing matrix multiplication). Matrices `a` and `b` represents/encode the block structure of `P` and the small `p` represents the values of each block.

Now, if you want to multiply (element-wise) `p` with a small (2x2) matrix `q` you simply

```
a @ (p * q) @ b
```

A simple pytorch example

```
In [1]: a = torch.tensor([[1., 0], [1., 0], [0., 1], [0, 1]])
In [2]: b = torch.tensor([[1., 1., 0, 0], [0, 0, 1., 1]]) 
In [3]: p=torch.tensor([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]])
In [4]: q = torch.tensor([[1., 0], [0., 0]])

In [5]: a @ p @ b
```

> ```
> Out[5]:
> tensor([[1., 1., 2., 2.],
>         [1., 1., 2., 2.],
>         [3., 3., 4., 4.],
>         [3., 3., 4., 4.]])
> ```

```
In [6]: a @ (p*q) @ b
```

> ```
> Out[6]:
> tensor([[1., 1., 0., 0.],
>         [1., 1., 0., 0.],
>         [0., 0., 0., 0.],
>         [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
> ```

I leave it to you as an exercise how to efficiently produce the "structure" matrices `a` and `b` given the sizes of the blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nice idea.

Comment: If the large matrix `P` follows this pattern (i.e. each partition has exactly the same number), the transformation from `p` to `P` and from `p * q` to the final outcome can be done using `reshape` and broadcasting as shown in my solution (from `m` to `mp`). Those operations are computationally much cheaper than matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the efficient method, but you can try these:

**Method 1:**

Using `torch.cat()`

```
import torch

def multiply(a, b):
    x1 = a[0:2, 0:2]*b[0,0]
    x2 = a[0:2, 2:]*b[0,1]
    x3 = a[2:, 0:2]*b[1,0]
    x4 = a[2:, 2:]*b[1,1]
    return torch.cat((torch.cat((x1, x2), 1), torch.cat((x3, x4), 1)), 0)

a = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 2, 2],[1, 1, 2, 2],[3, 3, 4, 4,],[3, 3, 4, 4]])
b = torch.tensor([[1, 0],[0, 0]])
print(multiply(a, b))
```

output:

```
tensor([[1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

**Method 2:**

Using `torch.nn.functional.pad()`

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch

def multiply(a, b):
    b = F.pad(input=b, pad=(1, 1, 1, 1), mode='constant', value=0)
    b[0,0] = 1
    b[0,1] = 1
    b[1,0] = 1
    return a*b

a = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 2, 2],[1, 1, 2, 2],[3, 3, 4, 4,],[3, 3, 4, 4]])
b = torch.tensor([[1, 0],[0, 0]])
print(multiply(a, b))
```

output:

```
tensor([[1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If the matrices are small, you are probably fine with `cat` or `pad`. The solution with factorization is very elegant, as the one with a `block_mul` implementation.

Another solution is turning the 2D block matrix in a 3D volume where each 2D slice is a block (`P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4`). Then use the power of broadcasting to multiply each 2D slice by a scalar. Finally reshape the output. Reshaping is not immediate but it's doable, port from numpy to pytorch of https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873755/4892874

In Pytorch:

```
import torch

h = w = 4
x = torch.ones(h, w)
x[:2, 2:] = 2
x[2:, :2] = 3
x[2:, 2:] = 4

# number of blocks along x and y
nrows=2
ncols=2

vol3d = x.reshape(h//nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
vol3d = vol3d.permute(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(-1, nrows, ncols)

out = vol3d * torch.Tensor([1, 0, 0, 0])[:, None, None].float()

# reshape to original
n, nrows, ncols = out.shape
out = out.reshape(h//nrows, -1, nrows, ncols)
out = out.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
out = out.reshape(h, w)

print(out)

tensor([[1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I haven't benchmarked this against the others, but this doesn't consume additional memory like padding would do and it doesn't do slow operations like concatenation. It has also ther advantage of being easy to understand and visualize.

You can generalize it to any situation by playing with `h, w, nrows, ncols`.

Comment: Does the `permute` operation create a copy of the original tensor?

Comment: no, the resulting tensor shares the same storage. The only copy is done at this line `out = out.reshape(h, w)`. Everything else is a view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The second solution is the thing which is very good for small matrices but for the big matrices, it'll be horrible.

Comment: I had added a solution that uses implicit broadcasting together with the original explicit broadcasting solution. As far as I understand, the broadcasting operations would not consume extra memory either.

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answer may be the solution, it is not an efficient way. I come up with another one to tackle the problem (**but still is not perfect**). The following implementation needs too much memory when our inputs are 3 or 4 dimensions. For example, for input size of 20*75*1024*1024, the following calculation needs around 12gb ram.

Here is my implementation:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()


inps = tf.constant([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]])

on_cells = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 1]])

on_cells = tf.expand_dims(on_cells, axis=-1)

# replicate the value to block-size (4*4)
on_cells = tf.tile(on_cells, [1, 1, 4 * 4])

# reshape to a format for permutation
on_cells = tf.reshape(on_cells, (1, 2, 2, 4, 4))

# permutation
on_cells = tf.transpose(on_cells, [0, 1, 3, 2, 4])

# reshape
on_cells = tf.reshape(on_cells, [1, 8, 8])

# element-wise operation
print(inps * on_cells)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
  [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
  [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
  [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 4 4 4 4]
  [0 0 0 0 4 4 4 4]
  [0 0 0 0 4 4 4 4]
  [0 0 0 0 4 4 4 4]]], shape=(1, 8, 8), dtype=int32)
```