# How to flatten only some dimensions of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, flatten

Is there a quick way to "sub-flatten" or flatten only some of the first dimensions in a numpy array?

For example, given a numpy array of dimensions `(50,100,25)`, the resultant dimensions would be `(5000,25)`

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990465/3d-numpy-array-to-2d

Comment: You need a refresher course on numpy ndarray array slicing.  Also known as multi dimensional array indexing, see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html  Array slice your ndarray using square brackets, and use the comma delimiter to separate how much of each dimension you want.   It will look something like (not exactly) this: `your_array[50:100, 7, :]` which flattens the 3d object to 2d, using only slice number 7 for the 2nd dimension.

Comment: ^ Slices just take a subset, the poster wants to retain all the datapoints. I assume you mean `array[0:50,7,:]` which gives size `(50,25)`, dropping 99% of the data.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Take a look at [numpy.reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) .

```
>>> arr = numpy.zeros((50,100,25))
>>> arr.shape
# (50, 100, 25)

>>> new_arr = arr.reshape(5000,25)
>>> new_arr.shape   
# (5000, 25)

# One shape dimension can be -1. 
# In this case, the value is inferred from 
# the length of the array and remaining dimensions.
>>> another_arr = arr.reshape(-1, arr.shape[-1])
>>> another_arr.shape
# (5000, 25)
```

Comment: Such solutions seem a tiny bit inelegant to me, as they require some redundant information. I wish there were a way to do this which only required specifying the subset of dimensions, something like `arr.flatten(dimensions=(0, 1))`.

Comment: @Denziloe one cannot simply 'flatten' an arbitrary dimension of an ndarray without specifying which dimension the extra data will be folded into.Take for example a 2x2x3 ndarray, flattening the last dimension can produce a 2x6 or 6x2, so the information isn't redundant. You can specify the dimension with a -1:
From [numpy.reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)
One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.
So a 2x2xN reshaped to a 2Nx2 looks like this:`arr.reshape((-1,2))`.

Comment: @Denziloe A way to achieve this may be something like `arr.reshape(arr.shape[0] * arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2])`

Comment: @אלימלךשרייבר Funny, torch seems to manage this somehow: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html ;)

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann,  numpy's [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) too would manage. Flatten, as implied by the function's name, flattens the tensor/ndarray into a 1-D array. So there is *no ambiguity that needs resolving.
Whereas the issue discussed here is the flattening of  a single dimension, e.g. a 6-D into a 5-D tensor/ndarray. 
[Torch Reshape](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html)needs the same specification in this regard.

Comment: thanks @AdrienPavao, I was looking for that! but what to do when dimensions to flatten are for instance dim=(0,2) ? Not clear to me, I guess swapping axis should do the job...

Comment: @אלימלךשרייבר You can't flatten a single axis, but you could easily flatten two axes. As an example you could flatten a 2x3x4 array like `np.flatten(arr, axes=(0,1))` to get an 6x4 array.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion There is no np.flatten, and np.ndarray.flatten takes only one argument: the array to flatten. You might be thinking of reshape.

Answer (score 122):

A slight generalization to Alexander's answer - np.reshape can take -1 as an argument, meaning "total array size divided by product of all other listed dimensions":

e.g. to flatten all but the last dimension:

```
>>> arr = numpy.zeros((50,100,25))
>>> new_arr = arr.reshape(-1, arr.shape[-1])
>>> new_arr.shape
# (5000, 25)
```

Answer (score 75):

A slight generalization to Peter's answer -- you can specify a range over the original array's shape if you want to go beyond three dimensional arrays.

e.g. to flatten all but the last *two* dimensions:

```
arr = numpy.zeros((3, 4, 5, 6))
new_arr = arr.reshape(-1, *arr.shape[-2:])
new_arr.shape
# (12, 5, 6)
```

EDIT: A slight generalization to my earlier answer -- you can, of course, also specify a range at the beginning of the of the reshape too:

```
arr = numpy.zeros((3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
new_arr = arr.reshape(*arr.shape[:2], -1, *arr.shape[-2:])
new_arr.shape
# (3, 4, 30, 7, 8)
```

Comment: It's been more than two years already... We need another slight generalization! ;)

Answer (score 18):

`numpy.vstack` is perfect for this situation

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.ones((50,100,25))
np.vstack(arr).shape
> (5000, 25)
```

I prefer to use `stack`, `vstack` or `hstack` over `reshape` because `reshape` just scans through the data and seems to brute-force it into the desired shape. This can be problematic if you are e.g. going to take column averages.

Here's an illustration of what I mean. Suppose we have the following array

```
>>> arr.shape
(2, 3, 4)
>>> arr 
array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]],

       [[7, 7, 7, 7],
        [7, 7, 7, 7],
        [7, 7, 7, 7]]])
```

We apply both methods to get an array of shape (3,8)

```
>>> arr.reshape((3,8)).shape
(3, 8)
>>> np.hstack(arr).shape 
(3, 8)
```

However if we look at how they have been reshaped in each case, the `hstack` would allow us to take column sums that we could also have calculated from the original array. With reshape this isn't possible.

```
>>> arr.reshape((3,8))
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]])
>>> np.hstack(arr)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7]])
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach is to use `numpy.resize()` as in:

```
In [37]: shp = (50,100,25)
In [38]: arr = np.random.random_sample(shp)
In [45]: resized_arr = np.resize(arr, (np.prod(shp[:2]), shp[-1]))
In [46]: resized_arr.shape
Out[46]: (5000, 25)

# sanity check with other solutions
In [47]: resized = np.reshape(arr, (-1, shp[-1]))
In [48]: np.allclose(resized_arr, resized)
Out[48]: True
```