# How do you flatten the last two dimensions of an numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, given a numpy array of dimensions (132, 82, 100), the resultant dimensions would be (132, 8200)

Comment: Just create a new array with the dimensions you want and insert the values as you would like them.

Comment: have you tried the 'reshape' method or the 'view' funciton?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flatten only some dimensions of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757742/how-to-flatten-only-some-dimensions-of-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [reshape()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) function to change shape of the array. Using -1 as a parameter to reshape tells numpy to infer the dimension there.

```
arr = np.zeros((132, 82, 100))
arr = arr.reshape(*arr.shape[:-2], -1)
print(arr.shape)
# Out: (132, 8200)
```