# Is it possible to flatten an array with two different major orders without using for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, flatten

In python, I would like to flatten an array that are 3 dimensional. Say shape `(10, 15, 200)`. But the first two would need to be flattened with row-major order while the remaining flatten operation would be done in column-major order.

I can probably do this in a `for` loop by iterating over operations like slicing the array, flattening it individually, and storing it in the main array. For example, I would slice the main array to be `(10, 15)` do a row-major flatten --> store it to the main with `(150, 200)`, and then do a column-major flatten operation.

I am not sure if this is the most efficient method of doing this. Is there a better way to do this using numpy calls?

Comment: Usually the answer is `map()` though depending on how you use `for` it can behave like a map call.

Comment: The first two _what_, though? If it's a single 3D array, that's not "three separate arrays" that you can flatten one after the other, it's a single 3D shape where each 3D coordinate has a unique value.

Comment: Maybe this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72299599/987358 can help a bit. For a better answer you may show code to create a simple sample array (e.g. `np.arange(24).reshape((2,3,4))`) and the expected result or some (slow) code that produces the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) with the default `"C"` ordering (row-major) on the first two dimensions and then use [`.flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) with the `"F"` ordering (column-major) for the final result.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5)
b = a.reshape(-1, a.shape[-1]).flatten("F")
```

Result:

```py
array([ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55,  1,  6, 11, 16, 21,
       26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56,  2,  7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47,
       52, 57,  3,  8, 13, 18, 23, 28, 33, 38, 43, 48, 53, 58,  4,  9, 14,
       19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49, 54, 59])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the last axis to the beginning.

```
np.moveaxis(a, -1, 0).flatten()
```

Comment: From timing I find this method to be a bit slower than `reshape` + `flatten` (how much slower depends on the array dimensions).