# Reshape of set of arrays in 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

In order to do calculations, I have a set of arrays: "sub" array (as you can see below), and I want to reshape it in an array as given by "test" array:

```
import numpy as np

sub = np.array([[[[ 1.,  1.],
         [ 1.,  1.]],

        [[ 2.,  2.],
         [ 2.,  2.]],

        [[ 3.,  3.],
         [ 3.,  3.]],

        [[ 4.,  4.],
         [ 4.,  4.]]],

       [[[ 5.,  5.],
         [ 5.,  5.]],

        [[ 6.,  6.],
         [ 6.,  6.]],

        [[ 7.,  7.],
         [ 7.,  7.]],

        [[ 8.,  8.],
         [ 8.,  8.]]]])


test=np.array([[[ 1.,  1.,  2., 2.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  2., 2.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  4., 4.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  4., 4.]],

       [[ 5.,  5.,  6., 6.],
        [ 5.,  5.,  6., 6.],
        [ 7.,  7.,  8., 8.],
        [ 7.,  7.,  8., 8.]]])
```

I have found on a post a part of code which seems to work for my case, but I have some errors...

```
k,l,m,n,p =2,2,2,2,2
conc = np.array([np.ones([p,m,n],dtype=int)*i for i in range(k*l)])
test_reshape=np.vstack([np.hstack(sub[i:i+l]) for i in range(0,k*l*p,l)])
```

Comment: It must be automated because the arrays are very important in my case :/

Comment: when the subarrays are not very important, it seems work...but not in all cases :/

Comment: "I have some errors...". Care to share them with us?

Comment: Thanks for help ;) First i want to say (for some errors) when i play on the size of subarrays or the array to decompose, i do reshape and some subarrays are not well placed...Then, i need to have a code automated because of my arrays are 400x250... :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative way to swap, slice and stack your array into shape:

```
>>> t = sub.swapaxes(1, 3).T.swapaxes(1, 3)
>>> x = np.c_[t[::2, 0], t[1::2, 0]]
>>> y = np.c_[t[::2, 1], t[1::2, 1]]
>>> np.array((np.r_[x[0], x[1]], np.r_[y[0], y[1]]))

array([[[ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  4.,  4.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  4.,  4.]],

       [[ 5.,  5.,  6.,  6.],
        [ 5.,  5.,  6.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  7.,  8.,  8.],
        [ 7.,  7.,  8.,  8.]]])
```

**Edit**: Or instead, squeeze, slice and stack:

```
>>> x = np.c_[sub[:1][:,::2], sub[:1][:,1::2]].squeeze()
>>> y = np.c_[sub[1:][:,::2], sub[1:][:,1::2]].squeeze()
>>> np.array((np.r_[x[0], x[1]], np.r_[y[0], y[1]]))
# the required array
```

Comment: Your solutions work perfectly with a `sub.shape` that is exactly that proposed by the OP, `(2,4,2,2)`, and so they both solve the OP question.  Is it possible to generalize/parametrize one of your solutions to work with a 4D -> 3D conversion of the type  `(m,4,r,c)` -> `(m,2*r,2*c)`?

Comment: Hi @gboffi - I _suspect_ it would be possible to adapt the slicing to the more general case, but it might require a bit of modification to the method I suggested. I've not tried yet, but will try to update my answer if I'm successful.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
sub = np.array(...)
test = np.array([np.hstack((np.vstack(( s[0],s[1] )),
                            np.vstack(( s[2],s[3] )))) for s in sub])
print test
```

In the OP's example the shape of `sub` is `(2,4,2,2)`, but that the code above would work *as is* for an array of shape `(n,4,m,m)`.  For different shapes of the type `(n,k,m,m)` the code above can be adapted to different requirements.

Eventually I would like to add that when you look at the code *you literally see* what the code is achieving, and this may be compensating other defects of the code in terms of efficiency (i.e., copying vs reshaping).

---

### A better solution (i.e, not mine ;-) and some aftertoughts

I have found [this answer from unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13990648/2749397) (that contains a link to a more general solution) that the OP can easily (?) adapt to  her/his needs.  Due to the complex reshaping that is 
involved data is however copied, hence the OP may want to measure the different performances of the two approaches, taking into account the incidence of the "reshaping" on the total run time of her/his program (i.e., imho shaving 0.3s on a runtime of 2' wouldn't be worth the effort)

#### Examplar interactive session

In the following, the data and the procedures are *literally* lifted from
[the above mentioned answer from unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13990648/2749397), with the last two statements added by me to show the addresses of the data buffers of the three `ndarray`s, `x`, `y` and `z`.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.arange(16).reshape((4,2,2))

In [3]: y = x.reshape(2,2,2,2).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(4,-1)

In [4]: x
Out[4]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15]]])

In [5]: y
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  3,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 12, 13],
       [10, 11, 14, 15]])

In [6]: z = x.T

In [7]: [a.__array_interface__['data'][0] for a in (x, y, z)]
Out[7]: [46375856, 45578800, 46375856]

In [8]:
```

Comment: ps: it works for any number of "top" elements in the array `subs`, the only assumption here is how to organize the stacking but you should be able to write code that generalizes my _ad hoc_ implementation

Comment: Hi @gboffi! In the future, if you need to write a PS for your own answer, feel free to put it into the answer's body. This makes it easier for it to stay in focus, as people may skip over comments.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there exists a pure numpy solution, but I'm not aware of it and it'll use quite a few tricks with strides. The solution below is thus not as efficient, because it uses python's for loops (making it less quick), but it 'll get your result in a *general* way, so without it depending on the size of your actual 4D array.

```
np.vstack( (sub[vol,2*sheet:2*sheet+2].reshape((4,-1)).T for vol in range(2) for sheet in range(2))).reshape((2,4,-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [a `reshape/swapaxes` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13990648/190597):

```
In [92]: sub.reshape(2,2,2,2,2).swapaxes(2,3).reshape(test.shape)
Out[92]: 
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  4.,  4.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  4.,  4.]],

       [[ 5.,  5.,  6.,  6.],
        [ 5.,  5.,  6.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  7.,  8.,  8.],
        [ 7.,  7.,  8.,  8.]]])

In [94]: np.allclose(sub.reshape(2,2,2,2,2).swapaxes(2,3).reshape(test.shape), test)
Out[94]: True
```

I confess I do not know how to generate this kind of solution without some guessing. But it appears that when you want to rearrange "blocks" in an array, there is a way to do it by reshaping to a higher dimension, swapping some axes, then reshaping to the desired shape. Given that `sub.shape` is `(2, 4, 2, 2)` reshaping to a higher dimension must mean `(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)`. So you only have to test for a solution of the form

```
sub.reshape(2,2,2,2,2).swapaxes(i,j).reshape(test.shape)
```

and that is easy to do:

```
for i,j in IT.combinations(range(5), 2):
    if np.allclose(sub.reshape(2,2,2,2,2).swapaxes(i,j).reshape(test.shape), test):
       print(i,j)
```

reveals the right axes to swap:

```
(2, 3)
```