# Combining scipy.optimize.brute grid and results

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am using scipy's brute optimizer to compute the scores of a function given different input parameters. In order to analyze the results, I want to dump the resulting parameter vs score sets into a csv.

What I currently have is the return from the brute optimizer, which from the docs is of the form:

Returns:
x0 : ndarray
A 1-D array containing the coordinates of a point at which the objective function had its minimum value. (See Note 1 for which point is returned.)
fval : float
Function value at the point x0.
grid : tuple
Representation of the evaluation grid. It has the same length as x0. (Returned when full_output is True.)
Jout : ndarray
Function values at each point of the evaluation grid, i.e., Jout = func(*grid). (Returned when full_output is True.)

[source](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html)

I want combine the "grid" value with the "Jout" parameter in the form of:

[Param1,Param2,Param3,Score1]
[Param1,Param2,Param3,Score2]
...

An example output from brute is:

```
     (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), -0.96868449202047968, array([[[[0, 0],
     [0, 0]],

    [[1, 1],
     [1, 1]]],


   [[[0, 0],
     [1, 1]],

    [[0, 0],
     [1, 1]]],


   [[[0, 1],
     [0, 1]],

    [[0, 1],
     [0, 1]]]]), array([[[-0.96868449, -0.96868449],
    [-0.96868449, -0.96868449]],

   [[-0.96868449, -0.96868449],
    [-0.96868449, -0.96868449]]]))
```

I cannot, for the life of me figure out how to combine the array in index 2 of above (the "grid") with the array in index 3 (the "Jout"). My np array foo is not up to snuff.

Any tips or pointers would be very appreciated and ease my frustrated brain of the last few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to stack the three (2,2,2) matrices in `grid` and the (2,2,2) matrix `Jout`? [np.stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack) could be what you need, i.e.:

```
In [26]: a = np.array([[[[0, 0],
    ...:      [0, 0]],
    ...: 
    ...:     [[1, 1],
    ...:      [1, 1]]],
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...:    [[[0, 0],
    ...:      [1, 1]],
    ...: 
    ...:     [[0, 0],
    ...:      [1, 1]]],
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...:    [[[0, 1],
    ...:      [0, 1]],
    ...: 
    ...:     [[0, 1],
    ...:      [0, 1]]]])

In [27]: b = np.array([[[-0.96868449, -0.96868449],
    ...:     [-0.96868449, -0.96868449]],
    ...: 
    ...:    [[-0.96868449, -0.96868449],
    ...:     [-0.96868449, -0.96868449]]])

In [28]: np.stack([*a, b], -1)
Out[28]: 
array([[[[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.96868449],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        , -0.96868449]],

        [[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        , -0.96868449],
         [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        , -0.96868449]]],


       [[[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.96868449],
         [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        , -0.96868449]],

        [[ 1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        , -0.96868449],
         [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        , -0.96868449]]]])

In [29]:
```

Comment: Awesome, this gets me most of the way there, I think, but how can I convert that final output into a flatter form, ie:  [[0,0,0,-0.96],[0,0,1,-0.96]]

Comment: Have a look at `numpy.reshape`.

Comment: edit: found it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990465/3d-numpy-array-to-2d) - thanks @tjollans!